# Getting the text out of a multi-line CEdit control?

Tags: c++, wtl, cedit

There has to be a better way to get the text from a multi-line CEdit control rather than using `GetLineCount()` then looping through all the lines and a appending the `GetLine(i)` to the end of an accumulator string. Is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CWindow::GetWindowText()`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6ca39fw(v=vs.80).aspx) and `CWindow::GetWindowTextLength()`

Comment: That doesn't appear to link to the WTL documentation (is there any?). Wrong casing, too.

Comment: @IInspectable WTL is built on top of ATL and CEdit is a CWindow.
That link above is from ATL documentation. Yet see: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3841/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-I-ATL-GUI-Classes